# How are values captured when assigning a function to something that retains a closure

Tags: swift, closures, block, reference-counting

If I have a class like this:

```
class Example {
    var emptyBlock: (Void -> Void)?
    var string: String = "Here's some string"
    func someFunction() {
        let string = self.string
        print(string)
    }
}
```

And I assign at some point:

```
let variable: Void -> Void = exampleInstance.someFunction
exampleInstance.emptyBlock = variable
```

Do I have a retain cycle because `variable` captures `exampleInstance` from `someFunction` and `variable` is retained by `exampleInstance`? Or is there some sort of magic that makes this not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test and I believe I've confirmed that they are in fact strongly captured as suspected.  I'll post my findings for anyone else who has this question:

Take this class, and breakpoint in `deinit`:

```
class Example {
    var emptyBlock: (Void -> Void)?
    var string: String = "Here's some string"
    func someFunction() {
        let string = self.string
        print(string)
    }

    deinit {
        print("I was deinitialized") // Breakpoint Here
    }
}
```

Then run these two examples of code:

**Reference Cycle**

Will not hit breakpoint because can't deinitialize:

```
let exampleInstance = Example()
let variable = exampleInstance.someFunction
exampleInstance.emptyBlock = variable
```

**Non-Reference Cycle**

Will hit breakpoint because weekly capturing:

```
let exampleInstance = Example()
let variable: Void -> Void = { [weak exampleInstance] in exampleInstance?.someFunction() }
exampleInstance.emptyBlock = variable
```

Because it hits the breakpoint when we weak capture, we can safely conclude that without that it is strongly captured as if a closure.

This should be considered when using this tool since we don't get the same obviousness of capture we do when declaring a closure.  There's no explicit warnings to call `self` to remind us, and there's no weak declarations within their scope.

**Guide**

I also found a reference in the guide:

> - Global functions are closures that have a name and do not capture any values.
> - Nested functions are closures that have a name and can capture values from their enclosing function.
> - Closure expressions are unnamed closures written in a lightweight syntax that can capture values from their surrounding context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a retain cycle. Assigning something to a local variable and then assigning it to something else is the same as assigning it directly. So that code is equivalent to

```
exampleInstance.emptyBlock = exampleInstance.someFunction
```

and `exampleInstance.someFunction` is just syntactic sugar for

```
{ x in exampleInstance.someFunction(x) }
```